# Get target id of appended element on angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have problem on getting the event.target.id on my angularjs project.

Heres the code i have:

**input-tag-to directive**

```
<input-tag-to></input-tag-to>
```

module:

```
angular
.module('emailClient').directive("inputTagTo", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<input type=text ng-model=toModel autofocus=true addtagto>",
    controller: 'composeController'
}});
```

and here's **addtagto** attribute on it

```
angular
.module('emailClient').directive("addtagto", function($compile) {
return { 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.addtoArray.push(scope.toModel);
                    var tagModel = scope.addtoArray.slice(-1)[0];
                    angular.element($('#to-box')).append($compile("<span class=\"box-tag\" style=\"padding: 3px;\" id=\""+ tagModel +"\">"+ tagModel +"<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" style=\"cursor:pointer;padding:4px;\" removetagto></span></span>")(scope));
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('.input-to').val("");
                    scope.toModel = null;
                    $('.input-to').focus();
            }

        });
    },
    controller: 'composeController'
}});
```

on the append element there is a directive **removeaddto** and `id="+ scope.toModel" +` on it.

Now I cant get event.target.id on it, in which i will use as value to remove its element

```
angular
.module('emailClient').directive("removetagto", function($compile) {
return { 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.target.id);
        });
    },
    controller: 'composeController'
    }});
```

see the sample image
[image]

[image]

console.log(event.currentTarget); **result: empty id**

Answer (score 0):

You need `$event.currentTarget` instead of `$event.target`

Comment: Still the id is empty, using event.currentTarget see here : console.log https://ctrlv.cz/en/9wjk

Comment: @nixongalario hi can you show the contents of your controller "composeController"